# Try to install mongodb with dijango?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pip, nosql

I am trying to configure MongoDB database to Django. I tried a lot of tutorials but still, I am not able to configure.

I followed following tutorials commands.

http://2buntu.com/articles/1451/installing-django-and-mongodb-in-your-virtualenv/

http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/

I added the following code to `setting.py` class.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
     'NAME'   : 'product'
}
```

I tried with different version too, but still I could not run this command.

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

I got following error.

```
  $ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

This is my current installed project packages.

```
$ pip list
django-mongodb-engine (0.6.0)
djangotoolbox (1.8.0)
pip (7.1.2)
pymongo (3.0.3)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

Expecting any expert help to do this. I did not find any latest article to do this.

I want to do this project using `dijango-1.8`, `python 3.x` and using `MongoDB`. I code on `linux-ubuntu(14.04)` machine, my system has both python 2x,3x version.

=========================After install Dijango 1.8===================

```
   $ python manage.py runserver
/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/utils.py:1: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import format_number

/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/utils.py:1: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import format_number

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fcf8b16ce60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 223, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 164, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 180, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
  File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 502, in schema_editor
    'The SchemaEditorClass attribute of this database wrapper is still None')
NotImplementedError: The SchemaEditorClass attribute of this database wrapper is still None
```

now pip list.

```
Django (1.8)
django-mongodb-engine (0.6.0)
djangotoolbox (1.8.0)
pip (7.1.2)
pymongo (3.0.3)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

Comment: Your `pip list` does not show `django` installed. Install Django.

Comment: @JRodDynamite thank you , I installed django 1.8 . now give big error or some thing. I edited question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you should install `django` from this repository - https://github.com/django-nonrel/django

Comment: You need to install this version of `django` since it has support for non-relational databases. You won't get version 1.8 though.

Comment: Also, from your logs, you are using python-2.7. I'd suggest that you should go through the tutorial once again. Follow this [tutorial](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html).

Comment: @JRodDynamite ,thank for your help.I will try another one time. I am really tired now, trying this. please can you post what set of command I would follow to install this. It will helpfull to other developer too. I think that article and content are older versions.

Comment: Did you activate virtualenv? Usually, ImportError: No module named django.core.management point to that. I work with django and mongodb, and make use of django-mongokit, pymongo. You may refer [this](https://github.com/gnowledge/gstudio/blob/mongokit/INSTALL)

Comment: yes, I activate virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After , big effort,I can configure Dijago.when I install some warning are aper. but I think ,sometime my installing order may be incorrect. I post this , because it may be help to others and if I do some wrong ,I want expert advice.

Installing packages.

```
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/test2$ pip list
    Django (1.6.11)
    django-dbindexer (1.6.1)
    django-mongodb-engine (0.6.0)
    djangotoolbox (1.8.0)
    pip (7.1.2)
    pymongo (3.0.3)
    setuptools (18.2)
    wheel (0.24.0)
```

Ubuntu terminal code

```
    umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ ls -l
total 0

umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ virtualenv myprojec
New python executable in myprojec/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ source myprojec/bin/activate

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/nonrel-1.6
Collecting https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/nonrel-1.6

/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/nonrel-1.6
     | 6.7MB 1.9MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Django
  Stored in directory: /home/umayanga/.cache/pip/wheels/89/cd/89/64475e53eef52b22b711705322a36352f2f979fdcef0e39e8a
Successfully built Django
Installing collected packages: Django
Successfully installed Django-1.6.11


(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 6 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:26 myprojec

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ cd myprojec/
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:26 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 include
drwxrwxr-x 3 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 local
-rw-rw-r-- 1 umayanga umayanga   60 Oct 10 15:26 pip-selfcheck.json

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ (myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ cd ..

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install pymongo
Collecting pymongo

/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo-3.0.3

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox to /tmp/pip-Lloitv-build
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-Lloitv-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox

  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): djangotoolbox==1.8.0 from git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...


(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install django-dbindexer

Collecting django-dbindexer
/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading django-dbindexer-1.6.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: django-dbindexer
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-dbindexer
  Stored in directory: /home/umayanga/.cache/pip/wheels/09/2f/ea/01d26e4ffc98cd2ed54b92f31a82aecccb8e7b5c9e3b28a8ca
Successfully built django-dbindexer
Installing collected packages: django-dbindexer
Successfully installed django-dbindexer-1.6.1


(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox

Collecting git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox to /tmp/pip-2AUZTq-build
Installing collected packages: djangotoolbox
  Running setup.py install for djangotoolbox
Successfully installed djangotoolbox-1.8.0

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
Collecting git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine to /tmp/pip-63Fwrm-build
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo>=2.8 in ./myprojec/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): djangotoolbox>=1.6.0 in ./myprojec/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0)
Installing collected packages: django-mongodb-engine
  Running setup.py install for django-mongodb-engine
Successfully installed django-mongodb-engine-0.6.0

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject$ cd myprojec

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ django-admin.py startproject myproject
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ ls -l
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:26 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 include
drwxrwxr-x 3 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:25 local
drwxrwxr-x 3 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:36 myproject
-rw-rw-r-- 1 umayanga umayanga   60 Oct 10 15:26 pip-selfcheck.json

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ (myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec$ cd myproject/

(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/myproject$ 
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/myproject$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxrwxr-x 1 umayanga umayanga  252 Oct 10 15:36 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 umayanga umayanga 4096 Oct 10 15:36 myproject
(myprojec)umayanga@umayanga-HP-630-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/myproject$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
October 10, 2015 - 10:06:57
Django version 1.6.11, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[10/Oct/2015 10:07:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1757
[10/Oct/2015 10:08:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1757
[10/Oct/2015 10:08:48] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[10/Oct/2015 10:08:48] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1865
```