# Running server error: "ImportError: No module named 'django'" in OS - X

Tags: python, django, localhost

I'm attempting to start up my first Django project. I have virtualenv setup and running with Django 1.8.5 installed. When I run `pip freeze` within my virtualenv I get:

```
Django==1.8.5  
wheel==0.24.0
```

I then CD into my project and run `python manage.py runserver` and get an error:

```
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I opened up my `manage.py` file and it contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "trydjango18.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Pip list:

```
Django (1.8.5)
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

I have attempted starting multiple projects, all give the same error. I have tried both with and without virtualenv (Django is also installed globally) to no avail. I've done a lot of research but haven't found any answers that fix my issue.

**EDIT** When stating up a new virtualenv and running `source bin/activate` for the first time I get the following message:

```
/Users/master/Desktop/testdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [importerror: No module named django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299710/importerror-no-module-named-django)

Comment: are you activate virtual environment ? '$ sudo source myprojec/bin/activate'

Comment: @uma virtual environment is activated. When I run `pip freeze` all that is outputed is what's mentioned above. It's running and should be working.

Comment: you try this command . 'python3 manage.py runserver'

Comment: @AndreL I don't believe it's a duplicate. I've read through that post and wasn't able to solve my issue. I'm able to run `import django` fine, but when I run runserver it's giving me an importerror for some reason.

Comment: @uma `python3 manage.py runserver` gives me the same error.

Comment: what os you use? can you give like this (terminal) out put. I guess trouble is mismatching version.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050190/try-to-install-mongodb-with-dijango

Comment: @uma I'm running OS X 10.10.3. I'll update post with pip list. I think that's what you're asking for?

Comment: ya.. some time that error caused to your OS trouble.I am doing in UBUNTU 14.04.  I think it better to get help from OS-X user. I will send you link , witch i can got success. one advice give you ,you try using below version like 1.7.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new virtualenv, and reinstalling Django? I know it sounds stupid... But believe me, sometimes that works. :)

Comment: @JoseRomero Yea unfortunately I've tried this various times in various locations and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @b4n4n4  , please use this tutorial , http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/installation/index.html . you follow every step carefully. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info . i am sure your trouble caused to some version mismatching.

Comment: @uma This worked! I didn't follow the entire tutorial but I just installed Python 3.4.3 and everything runs now. I guess there was an issue with version mismatching.

Comment: @b4n4n4 :-)  nice to hear that. I will post answer to your , Question ,if you can accept and up-vote me.

Comment: @uma after a bit more testing I've realized updating to Python 3 didn't solve the issue but rather running the command listed in the tutorial you listed did. I was setting up virtualenv by running `virtualenv .` in my directory. This created all virtualenv files. The tutorial mentioned to create a virtualenv by running `python3 -m venv myvenv` and for whatever reason this fixed my issue. Unclear why.

Comment: I realize, your computer have Install both python 2.x and python 3.x. Default run python 2.x. when you type , Default  , it create virtual environment python 2.x. so , you should specify  python version when create virtual environment.As i remember Django 1.8 not support to python 2.x. I think now , you received some answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first ,you can also try this command.

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

According to my experience, I think your trouble caused to some packages miss matching reason.so , It is better check documentation ,If you do every thing correctly. please , check Django official site.

I have lot of experience about work with OS-X. because I work in UBUNTU 14.04.This some example I , installed Django.you can refer it.[install Django with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050190/try-to-install-mongodb-with-dijango)

I will successfully , install using following tutorials.I recommend you also refer that and reinstall .

[Django Girls Tutorial](http://%20tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/installation/index.html)

[About django](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info)

=====================Answer to your comment====================

I realize, your computer have Install both python 2.x and python 3.x.
Default run python 2.x. when you create virtual environment , default it make it for python 2.x. so , you should specify  python version when create virtual environment.As I remember Django 1.8 not support to python 2.x. I think now , you received some answer.